# Local quadratic approximation of a scale-space in image processing

Tags: partial-derivative, approximation

I'm dealing with a Local-approximation of a scale-space in image processing. The approximation I deal with reads as follows:
$L(u+\xi,v+\eta,\sigma)\approx L(u,v,\sigma)+\frac{\partial L}{\partial u} \cdot \xi+\frac{\partial L}{\partial v} \cdot \eta + \frac{1}{2}\cdot (\xi,\eta) \cdot \mathbf{H} \cdot (\xi,\eta)^T$
with $\mathbf{H}$ being the Hessian-Matrix. Now the next step in my text book is that they just leave out the middle part with the first partial derrivatives and say:
$=L(u,v,\sigma)+ \frac{1}{2}\cdot (\xi,\eta) \cdot \mathbf{H} \cdot (\xi,\eta)^T$
Why is that possible?

Comment: It is possible if you're at some kind of critical point (max, min, or saddle) so that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial u} \cdot \xi+\frac{\partial L}{\partial v} \cdot \eta = 0$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Indeed, that'll be it, thank you. It's confusing that they don't mention that there is a restriction for this equation transformation.  
If you make this an answer I'll accept